# Obter intervalos de horas livres somente com SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou criando uma agenda e preciso realizar uma consulta do intervalo entre os horários agendados.

Exemplo:

```
Tabela: HORARIO_ATENDIMENTO
INICIO: 08:00
FIM:    18:00

Tabela: Agenda

ID: 1
HORA_INICIAL: 08:00
HORA_FINAL:   09:00

ID: 2
HORA_INICIAL: 10:00
HORA_FINAL:   11:00
```

---

Neste cenário, temos os horários LIVRES: 09:00-10:00 e das 11:00-18:00 e é esta informação que gostaria de visualizar diretamente na consulta. Pesquisei aqui no stack e não encontrei algo que me dê um norte.

Supondo que exista apenas 1 único dia e realizando uma consulta simples, teríamos:

```
SELECT id,hora_inicial,hora_final FROM agenda;

Resultado:
1 - 08:00 - 09:00
2 - 10:00 - 11:00
```

Resumindo, gostaria de que os dados retornados fossem:

```
Resultado:
1 - 09:00-10:00 
2 - 11:00-18:00
```

**OBS:** O resultado final eu já consegui via código (PHP), mas gostaria de fazer isso via SQL, pois tenho dúvidas quanto ao desempenho.

*Caso necessário, posso postar o código, mas como a dúvida não é nele, e sim em como construir o SQL "inverso" digamos assim, não achei necessário postar.*

Comment: Olá Felipe. Puramente com SQL não imaginei uma forma de atingir o resultado esperado. Acredito que seja possível com uma procedure usando um SQL Server (T-SQL) ou Oracle (PLSQL). Entretanto não considero esse calculo de data "lento" dentro da camada de aplicação (PHP no caso);

Comment: Sua tabela deverá ter todos os horários disponíveis , o horário de trabalho , um campo sinaliza se o horário está ocupado ou não

Comment: Pensando em seu problema, e sem ter procedure e afins, eu imagino da seguinte maneira. Uma tabela de configuração da agenda, aonde você teria o intervalo de cada horário e hora inicio / fim.

Comment: A questão é que os horários são flexíveis e múltiplos de 1 minuto, ou seja, o cara pode agendar um horário das 08:00 até as 08:33 por exemplo, ou seja, e altamente flexível quanto a horário. Eu gostei da questão das procedures estarei estuando elas. Obrigado a todos por tentar ajudar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Você conseguiria atingir esse resultado com uma procedure.
Levando o seu exemplo ao pé da letra desenvolvi rapidamente duas procedures para te ajudar a atingir esse resultado, veja: (MySql)

```
DROP DATABASE TEST;
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
USE TEST;
CREATE TABLE agenda(ID int ,HORA_INICIAL time ,HORA_FINAL time);
CREATE TABLE horario_atendimento(INICIO time ,FIM time);
CREATE TABLE horario_livre(INICIO time ,FIM time);
select * from agenda;
select * from horario_atendimento;
insert into horario_atendimento(INICIO,FIM) values ('08:00:00','18:00:00');
insert into agenda(ID,HORA_INICIAL,HORA_FINAL) values(1,'08:00:00','09:00:00');
insert into agenda(ID,HORA_INICIAL,HORA_FINAL) values(2,'10:00:00','11:00:00');
truncate table horario_livre;
call TEST.new_procedure();
call TEST.new_procedure2();
select * from TEST.horario_livre;
```

**PROCEDURE1**

```
USE `TEST`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `TEST`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE limite INT;
    DECLARE idmin INT;
    DECLARE inicio time;
    DECLARE fim time;
    SELECT 
    MIN(ID)
INTO idmin FROM
    TEST.agenda;
    SELECT 
    COUNT(ID)
INTO limite FROM
    TEST.agenda;
WHILE contador<limite DO
            select HORA_FINAL into fim from TEST.agenda where ID =idmin;
            SET idmin = idmin + 1;
            SELECT 
    HORA_INICIAL
INTO inicio FROM
    TEST.agenda
WHERE
    ID = idmin; 
    IF (fim-inicio)<>0 THEN
                INSERT INTO TEST.horario_livre(INICIO ,FIM) values(fim,inicio);
                END IF;
        SET contador = contador + 1;
END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**PROCEDURE 2**

```
USE `TEST`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure2`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `TEST`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure2`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE idmax INT;
    DECLARE fimt time;
    DECLARE fimexpediente time;
SELECT 
    MAX(ID)
INTO idmax FROM
    TEST.agenda;
        SELECT 
    HORA_FINAL
INTO fimt FROM
    TEST.agenda
WHERE
    ID = idmax;
        SELECT 
    FIM
INTO fimexpediente FROM
    TEST.horario_atendimento;   
                INSERT INTO TEST.horario_livre(INICIO ,FIM) values(fimt,fimexpediente);     
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cara, obrigado, eu estou usando postgres mas o conceito é o mesmo e é disso que eu precisava.. vou realizar os testes aqui de acordo com o seu exemplo.